# Encrypt/Decrypt files using Carrierwave and storing in S3 (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I need to be able to encrypt files before storing them on S3, and then decrypt them when accessing them. The files will be images, documents, PDF, etc.

I am using Carrierwave to handle the file upload and storage (this is with Ruby on Rails). I am storing them in Amazon S3.

Has anyone done this, or have any ideas how this would be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon has now released functionality that lets you encrypt/decrypt files automatically in S3. The need to do this yourself is no longer there. Details are here http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingEncryption.html

Comment: Amazon SSE is not what most people are looking for in encryption. You want to protect customer files when your server gets hacked. Amazon SSE doesn't help when someone gains access to your S3 credentials.

Comment: I think this is the first time I have been downvoted when I answered my own question.  This did in fact solve my problem.

Comment: I'm assuming you used "Amazon Server Side Encryption", because if you were to use Amazon Client Side Encryption the "need" to mess with keys doesn't magically disappear. I believe that the purpose of encrypting uploaded files is to minimize the amount of data accessible to someone who hacks your server. Amazon SSE doesn't really help here.

Answer (score 3):

To handle the encryption, you should look into implementing a processor.  If you are using any other processors, you may have to look at extending the Carrierwave gem and adding a processor ordering mechanism so you can be sure encryption happens last.

For the decryption, you can either override the existing accessor to make the decryption transparent, or add a new method that returns the decrypted file and use that in place of the accessor.  The latter approach is probably more resilient to upstream changes.

Comment: I don't expect to use any other processor, any idea what processor I could use for encryption?

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is a few months old, but if you're still looking for answers, check out the carrierwave_securefile gem I wrote.  It's still new and probably a bit buggy on other setups, but it uses Crypt19 for Blowfish encryption on files prior to upload.

http://github.com/dougc84/carrierwave_securefile

Comment: Thanks I will check it out, however since Amazon released their own encryption for S3 I don't think I will need to deal with it anymore.